# Word describing "State goes back to original state after state-modifying actions A followed by ~A"

Tags: mathematics, technical

This word is slipping my mind and it is driving me crazy.  Not sure if it is a math term or computer science term, but I use it a lot in development (when I can remember it!)

Basically, you have the system in some state S.  You perform action A on the state putting it in S'.  Now you apply the opposite action, ~A.  The system is now back to state S because this set of actions acting on this system are _____.

Comment: .... Reversible.

Comment: Well, I'm almost certain the word you're looking for is *idempotent*, but it doesn't have the meaning hot describe. The state of *idempotent* systems do not change in response to external stimuli. So applying any external stimulus is, in a sense, "safe".

Comment: If Action P sets a state and Action Q unsets it, P and Q might be said to be *complementary*.

Comment: @DanBron Yes, sorry, the description does not fit the meaning exactly and I probably use it somewhat inappropriately since I do not know of a word that makes more sense.  In the case I am describing, somebody is toggling a button in some software (think: click on, click off, click on), which should not change the overall state.  Thanks, that was the one.

Comment: Reciprocal? Inverse?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like an [Inverse Function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSmFzOpxhbY), which is beautifully explained in this Youtube video. He takes a number, plugs it into an equation with an **inverse function**, and the answer is the number he started out with.

Comment: @JJJ - Because it's the inverse function of A.

Comment: @JJJ - You have explained that in your own answer which is right here on the same page. So why do you feel you must argue your case in the comments of my answer?

Comment: Mathematician here. @Bread is correct: the two actions are **inverses of each other**.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan Wouldn't you say that by the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) the two are equivalent? The two actions are each others inverses if and only if the two actions are injective.

Comment: @JJJ: No, you are very much mistaken. The Schroder-Bernstein Theorem says that if you have an injective function f:A->B and an injective function g:B->A then **there must exist** some bijective function h:A->B. However, this does not necessarily imply that f and g must have been inverses of each other to begin with. (Indeed, if that were the case, then f would already necessarily be a bijection from A to B, and we would not even require the result of the theorem.)

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan Thanks for clarifying, that makes sense.

Comment: @JJJ: Always glad to put my expertise to use :-)